# JQuery hidden checkbox checking, but not unchecking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have created a replacement img checkbox for the site I am working on. I can successfully get the checkbox to `check`, but not to `uncheck`. I can see this change in Inspect.

What is wrong with the code? There are no errors in the page. Thanks!

HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="AcceptTerms_check" name="AcceptTerms_check" style="display:none;">
<img class="chk-img" id="AcceptTerms" onclick="CheckboxClick(this);" src="../../../wp-content/uploads/misc/notselected.png">
<span id="ts-cs-accept">I have read and accepted the terms</span>.
```

JS is:

```
function CheckboxClick(element) {
    if(jQuery('input:checkbox[name=' + element.id + '_check]').is(":checked")) {
        jQuery('input:checkbox[name=' + element.id + '_check]').attr('checked','false');
        jQuery(element).attr("src", "../../../wp-content/uploads/misc/notselected.png");
    } else {
        jQuery('input:checkbox[name=' + element.id + '_check]').attr('checked','true');
        jQuery(element).attr("src", "../../../wp-content/uploads/misc/selected.png");
    };
};
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use `prop` with checkboxes, as you can use `true` and `false` values directly. You can also reduce your code a lot and not repeat complex jQuery selectors:

```
function CheckboxClick(element) {
    var $checkbox = jQuery('input:checkbox[name=' + element.id + '_check]')
    if($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
        $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
        jQuery(element).attr("src", "../../../wp-content/uploads/misc/notselected.png");
    } else {
        $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
        jQuery(element).attr("src", "../../../wp-content/uploads/misc/selected.png");
    };
};
```

*This can be simplified further, but I wanted you to still recognize your code* :)

e.g. you can toggle it with:

```
$checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
```

Update... Do not use attribute based events with jQuery (e.g. `onclick=`), use the jQuery way:

Try this way instead: http://jsfiddle.net/noy45sjg/1/

```
jQuery('.chk-img').click(function (e) {
    var element = jQuery(this);
    var $checkbox = jQuery('input:checkbox[name=' + this.id + '_check]');
    if($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
        $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
        jQuery(element).attr("src", "../../../wp-content/uploads/misc/notselected.png");
    } else {
        $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
        jQuery(element).attr("src", "../../../wp-content/uploads/misc/selected.png");
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't a boolean value you need to provide. true and false and not 'true' and 'false'

Comment: Hey TrueBlueAussie another late night for you too! Your suggestion works on changing the image but I cannot see the checkbox (in inspect) change to checked and back. I added an alert with `alert(jQuery('input:checkbox[name=' + element.id + '_check]').val());` at the end of your code and the alert shows `on` always.

Comment: @TheRealPapa: Practical working fiddle added. If you use an odd browser you may need to add `alt` text to the image to see it in the fiddle.

Comment: AWESOME, many thanks! I have some paid work if you are interested. How do I contact you via email?

Comment: Glad it helped. Go though my website link contact page. I get enough spam already without posting it here :) Cheers.